# implementing balanceOf in an ERC20 contract (not using openzepellin)

Tags: mapping, balances

I'm a noob and trying to implement the balanceOf function in a solidity. The standard API is

`function balanceOf (address account) public returns(uint256)`

However, I suspect that it needs to read the balance from a mapping. But the mapping had not been defined. Does it need to? Would the correct way to do this be this below? Defining a mapping before the function.

```
 mapping(address => uint256) internal balances;

function balanceOf (address account) public returns(uint256){ 
    return balances[account];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using EIP-20 as a reference in your implementation.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

With that being said it's entirely up to you to define the logic for each function. I would agree that doing a mapping of each address to a balance is a sufficient approach to implementing `balanceOf`, in fact this is exactly how [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L16) and [ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/fdf687c69d998266a95f15216b1955a4965a0a6d/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol#L14) have done it. Another approach would be to use `Storage` contracts as shown [here](https://github.com/solidstate-network/solidstate-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/base/ERC20BaseStorage.sol).

I would also add that your `balanceOf` function does not change state of the contract and therefore have its visibility set to `view`.